# Pushing data to an array in Angular 4 component from JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, for-loop

So, basically, I am trying to add all the albums of each artist in a JSON file, including the nested albums (which I am especially having a hard time with), into an array named `albums` in my `AlbumComponent`.

The overall solution I am trying to figure out and learn is specifically adding each album into an array so that I can make an `Albums` component.  This page displays each album and they are NOT coupled with other albums with the same artist. This way I can organize them alphabetically, etc.

Hopefully, I have the right thought process with this problem!

Anyway, here's the code:

Here is the data being provided by the service, and being injected into the component (and others). Notice that the artist `'Flume'` has two albums, and the other albums only have one (so far).

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  constructor() { }

  data = {
    "artists": [
      {
        "artistName": "Lupe Fiasco",
        "artistsPicture": "../assets/artists-images/lupe.jpg",
        "genre": "Hip-Hop",
        "albums": [
          { "name": "Food & Liquor",
            "albumCover": "../assets/album-covers/f&l.jpg",
            "songs": {
              "name": "Kick, Push",
              "file": "mp3"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "artistName": "Flume",
        "artistsPicture": "../assets/artists-images/flume.jpg",
        "genre": "",
        "albums": [
          { "name": "Flume",
            "albumCover": "../assets/album-covers/flume.jpg",
            "songs": {
              "name": "Sleepless",
              "file": "mp3"
            }
          },
          { "name": "Skin",
            "albumCover": "../assets/album-covers/skin.png",
            "songs": {
              "name": "Sleepless",
              "file": "mp3"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "artistName": "Linkin Park",
        "artistsPicture": "../assets/artists-images/linkinpark.jpg",
        "genre": "",
        "albums": [
          { "name": "Hybrid Theory",
            "albumCover": "../assets/album-covers/meteora.jpg",
            "songs": {
              "name": "Sleepless",
              "file": "mp3"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "artistName": "Drake",
        "artistsPicture": "../assets/artists-images/drake.jpg",
        "genre": "",
        "albums": [
          { "name": "Views",
            "albumCover": "../assets/album-covers/views.png",
            "songs": {
              "name": "Sleepless",
              "file": "mp3"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "artistName": "J.Cole",
        "artistsPicture": "../assets/artists-images/jcole.jpg",
        "genre": "",
        "albums": [
          { "name": "2014 Forest Hills Drive",
            "albumCover": "../assets/album-covers/fhd.jpg",
            "songs": {
              "name": "Sleepless",
              "file": "mp3"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "artistName": "Eminem",
        "artistsPicture": "../assets/artists-images/eminem.jpg",
        "genre": "",
        "albums": [
          { "name": "Marshal Matthers LP",
            "albumCover": "../assets/album-covers/mmlp.jpg",
            "songs": {
              "name": "Sleepless",
              "file": "mp3"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  }


}
```

**Component HTML**. This is the part that inspired this question. When I loop like this, the two `'Flume'` albums are coupled together in the UI. 
NoooOOooOOOOooOOO

So it achieves displaying each album cover, but fails on keeping them separate from other albums that are from the same artist.

```
<div *ngFor='let x of artistData.artists'>
  <img *ngFor='let x of x.albums' src="{{x.albumCover}}" alt="">
</div>
```

So my solution was trying to sort this all out in the component before I display it in the UI. Here is the component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './../../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-albums',
  templateUrl: './albums.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./albums.component.css']
})
export class AlbumsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  artistData = this.dataService.data;

  albums: any[] = [];


  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.albums);

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *flatten* your individual albums into a single array, instead of a nested array inside the artist object.  There's several implementations possible, here I used `Array.prototype.reduce()`.

**Add to Component logic**

```
const flatAlbums = data.artists.reduce((acc, next) => {
  next.albums.forEach(album => {
    acc.push(album);
  });
  return acc;
}, []);
```

Result of `console.log(flatAlbums)`:

```
[ { name: 'Food & Liquor',
    albumCover: '../assets/album-covers/f&l.jpg',
    songs: { name: 'Kick, Push', file: 'mp3' } },
  { name: 'Flume',
    albumCover: '../assets/album-covers/flume.jpg',
    songs: { name: 'Sleepless', file: 'mp3' } },
  { name: 'Skin',
    albumCover: '../assets/album-covers/skin.png',
    songs: { name: 'Sleepless', file: 'mp3' } },
  { name: 'Hybrid Theory',
    albumCover: '../assets/album-covers/meteora.jpg',
    songs: { name: 'Sleepless', file: 'mp3' } },
  { name: 'Views',
    albumCover: '../assets/album-covers/views.png',
    songs: { name: 'Sleepless', file: 'mp3' } },
  { name: '2014 Forest Hills Drive',
    albumCover: '../assets/album-covers/fhd.jpg',
    songs: { name: 'Sleepless', file: 'mp3' } },
  { name: 'Marshal Matthers LP',
    albumCover: '../assets/album-covers/mmlp.jpg',
    songs: { name: 'Sleepless', file: 'mp3' } } ]
```

**Modify Component HTML**

Only iterate over the new `flatAlbums` array.

```
<div *ngFor='let x of flatAlbums'>
  <img src="{{x.albumCover}}" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much :D I forgot all about .reduce() ahh.

Comment: @EddieTaliaferroII Happy it works for you.  `.reduce()` is probably my MOST favorite method in all of JavaScript.  Incredibly powerful.

Comment: one more thing, im having a hard time understanding the two parameters for the function in the reduce method (acc, next). Care to help me on that?

Comment: I'd start with the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) example.  Besides the obvious parts, the optional 2nd argument, in this case: `[]` (1st arg, being the reducer function), instantiates the `acc` as an empty array.  `next` is just the next value found, in the original array as it's being iterated over.  Furthermore, if I hadn't provided the 2nd optional argument `[]`, then the `acc` automatically is instantiated as the first value in the array being iterated over, and `next` starts at the 2nd value. Make sense?

Comment: @EddieTaliaferroII It took me a long time and concentrated study to understand the power of `.reduce()`.  [Here](https://github.com/TobiahRex/computerScience/tree/master/reduce) is a public repo of my studies, and the `.reduce()` portion specifically.  Perhaps you'll find it helpful to understand what I mean when i say "Powerful".

Comment: again, thanks. This is definitely a hole in my game and i am going to spend some time tonight studying this so that i can get better